# Grouping Herarchical Parent-Child data using Pandas Dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hierarchy

I have a data frame which I want to group based on the value of another column in the same data frame.

For example:

The Parent_ID and Child ID are linked and defines who is related to who in a hierarchical tree.

The dataframe looks like (input from a csv file)

```
No  Name    ID  Parent_Id
1   Tom     211 111
2   Galie   209 111
3   Remo    200 101
4   Carmen  212 121
5   Alfred  111 191
6   Marvela 101 111
7   Armin   234 101
8   Boris   454 109
9   Katya   109 323
```

I would like to group this data frame based on the ID and Parent_ID in the below grouping, and generate CSV files out of this based on the top level parent. I.e, Alfred.csv, Carmen.csv (will have only its own entry, ice line #4) , Katya.csv using the to_csv() function.

```
Alfred
  |_ Galie
   _ Tom
   _ Marvela
       |_ Remo
        _ Armin
Carmen
Katya
  |_ Boris
```

And, I want to create a new column in the same data frame, that will have a tag indicating the hierarchy. Like:

```
No  Name    ID  Parent_Id   Tag
1   Tom     211 111     Alfred
2   Galie   209 111     Alfred
3   Remo    200 101     Marvela, Alfred
4   Carmen  212 121 
5   Alfred  111 191 
6   Marvela 101 111     Alfred
7   Armin   234 101     Marvela, Alfred
8   Boris   454 109     Katya
9   Katya   109 323
```

Note that the names can repeat, but the ID will be unique.

Kindly let me know how to achieve this using pandas. I tried out groupby() but seems a little complicated and not getting what I intend. There should be one file for each parent, and the child records in the parent file. 
If a child has other child (like marvel), it qualifies to have its own csv file.

And the final output would be

```
Alfred.csv - All records matching Galie, Tom, Marvela
Marvela.csv - All records matching Remo, Armin
Carmen.csv - Only record matching carmen (row)
Katya.csv - all records matching katya, boris
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a recursive function to do this.

First, create dictionary of `{id:name}`, `{parent:id}` and the recursive function.

```
id_name_dict = dict(zip(df.ID, df.Name))
parent_dict = dict(zip(df.ID, df.Parent_Id))

def find_parent(x):
    value = parent_dict.get(x, None)
    if value is None:
        return ""
    else:
        # Incase there is a id without name.
        if id_name_dict.get(value, None) is None:
            return "" + find_parent(value)

        return str(id_name_dict.get(value)) +", "+ find_parent(value)
```

Then create the new column with `Series.apply` and remove `', '` with `Series.str.strip`

```
df['Tag'] = df.ID.apply(lambda x: find_parent(x)).str.rstrip(', ')

df

   No     Name   ID  Parent_Id              Tag
0   1      Tom  211        111           Alfred
1   2    Galie  209        111           Alfred
2   3     Remo  200        101  Marvela, Alfred
3   4   Carmen  212        121                 
4   5   Alfred  111        191                 
5   6  Marvela  101        111           Alfred
6   7    Armin  234        101  Marvela, Alfred
7   8    Boris  454        109            Katya
8   9    Katya  109        323
```

Comment: Thankyou ResidentSleeper! That looks like it. However, I am getting error with setcopy:SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df['Tag'] = df.ID.apply(lambda x: find_parent(x)).str.rstrip(', ')

Comment: @sidman Maybe your `df` is a copy of a slice. You can try `df = df.copy` before  or `df.loc[:, 'Tag'] = df.ID.apply(lambda x: find_parent(x)).str.rstrip(', ')` .